# Write back strategy for Memcache on GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, caching, google-cloud-datastore

My App Engine (Java) application is planned to work on a data structure that needs frequent updates on many items. The amount of data is not planned to exceed 1000 records (per client) but the amount of clients is unlimited so I'm not willing to do 1000 reads and 1000 writes every second just to update some counters.

Naturally I'm thinking about utilizing the Memcache. Ideally the data should be in memory all the time so I can read and update it frequently. It should only be written to the data storage if the cache is full or the VM is being shut down (my biggest concern). Can I implement some sort of [write-back strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_%28computing%29#Writing_policies) where the cache is only written to the storage when it needs to?

In particular my two questions are:

1. How do I know when an item is deleted from the cache?
2. How do I know when the VM is being shut down, so I can persist the content of the cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Longer answer: Memcache offers no guarantees.

Useful answer: Look at https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/scaling/memcache#transient. If losing data is an option, you can rely on memcache (but sometimes some things might be lost).

Don't worry about the VM being shut down though: Memcache runs outside of the instance VM, and is shared between all the app instance VMs.

Comment: Thanks for answering. If the Memcache runs outside the VM, can I place an entry into the cache and it will still be there tomorrow even if the instance isn't started once?

Comment: Yes, but without guarantees: It might not be there the next day.

Comment: Must empahisize its a big "NO GUARANTEES."  design you application so that it can deal with the data missing in memcache in just a few minutes.  ie writing to memcache and hoping to get it to the datastore some time later will only work if you don't mind missing some data some of the time.

Comment: Oh and you won't be told its gone, it just won't be there.  It is a cache.